# ¿Con cuáles clases puedo usar el método super() en Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo, clase, diseño-de-clases

Estoy aprendiendo Python, y me encontraba realizando un ejercicio sobre herencia:

Tengo la duda de que tan correcto sería usar el método **super()** en las clases nietas(por así decirlo), para heredar los atributos de las clases hijas que a la vez heredan de la clase padre.

Añado un poco de código.

```
# Clase padre
class Vehiculo():

    def __init__(self, co, ru):
        self.color = co
        self.ruedas = ru

# Clase hija
class Coche(Vehiculo):

    def __init__(self, co, ru, ve, ci):
        super().__init__(co, ru)
        self.velocidad = ve
        self.cilindrada = ci
```

¿Para la clase nieta que función de las siguientes puedo colocar, o es insignificativo?:

```
# Clase nieta
class Camioneta(Coche):

    # ésta?
    def __init__(self, co, ru, ve, ci, ca):
        super().__init__(co, ru, ve, ci)
        self.carga = ca

    # o ésta?
    def __init__(self, co, ru, ve, ci, ca):
        Coche.__init__(self, co, ru, ve, ci)
        self.carga = ca
```

Por si sirve de algo, dejo todo el código del ejercicio:

```
# Clase padre
class Vehiculo():

    def __init__(self, co, ru):
        self.color = co
        self.ruedas = ru

# Clase hija
class Coche(Vehiculo):

    def __init__(self, co, ru, ve, ci):
        super().__init__(co, ru)
        self.velocidad = ve
        self.cilindrada = ci

    def __str__(self):
        c = "Color: {}\nRuedas: {}\nVelocidad: {} km/h\nCilindrada: {}"
        return c.format(self.color,self.ruedas,self.velocidad,self.cilindrada)

# Clase hija
class Bicicleta(Vehiculo):

    def __init__(self, co, ru, ti):
        super().__init__(co, ru)
        self.tipo = ti

    def __str__(self):
        b = "Color: {}\nRuedas: {}\nTipo: {}"
        return b.format(self.color,self.ruedas,self.tipo)

# Clase nieta
class Camioneta(Coche):

   # def __init__(self, co, ru, ve, ci, ca):
   #    super().__init__(co, ru, ve, ci)
   #    self.carga = ca

    def __init__(self, co, ru, ve, ci, ca):
        Coche.__init__(self, co, ru, ve, ci)
        self.carga = ca

    def __str__(self):
        c = "Color: {}\nRuedas: {}\nVelocidad: {} km/h\nCilindrada: {}\nCarga: {} kg."
        return c.format(self.color,self.ruedas,self.velocidad,self.cilindrada,self.carga)

# Clase nieta
class Motocicleta(Bicicleta):

    # def __init__(self, co, ru, ti, ve_m, ci_m):
    #   super().__init__(co, ru, ti)
    #   self.velocidad = ve_m

    #   self.cilindrada = ci_m

    def __init__(self, co, ru, ti, ve_m, ci_m):
        Bicicleta.__init__(self, co, ru, ti)
        self.velocidad = ve_m
        self.cilindrada = ci_m

    def __str__(self):
        m = "Color: {}\nRuedas: {}\nTipo: {}\nVelocidad: {}\nCilindrada: {}"
        return m.format(self.color,self.ruedas,self.tipo,self.velocidad,self.cilindrada)

# Función que muestra el nombre del vehículo y sus atributos.
# Así como los vehículos en los que concuerde el num de ruedas (optativo)
def catalogar(lista, r = None):

    num = 0

    for i in vehiculos:
        print("\tClase: " + type(i).__name__)
        print(i)
        print("\n")

    if r is not None:
        for i in vehiculos:
            if i.ruedas == r:
            num += 1
        print(f"Se han encontrado {num} vehículos con {r} ruedas")


coche = Coche("rojo", 4, 240, 4)
bicicleta = Bicicleta("azúl", 2, "deportiva")
camioneta = Camioneta("negra", 4, 180, 8, 90)
motocicleta = Motocicleta("verde", 2, "urbana", 80, 4)

vehiculos = [coche, bicicleta, camioneta, motocicleta]

catalogar(vehiculos, 4)
```

*¡Muchas gracias!*

**Pd**: es mi primera vez preguntando algo en StackOverflow

Comment: tu *clase nieta* es la hija de una clase, por lo que esa clase es la *clase padre*. el uso `super()` solo vuelve más fácil poder inicializar otras clases, puedes hacer `padre.__init__(*args)` y funcionará igual, `super()` solo te hace más fácil la vida :)

Answer (score 2):

En tu ejemplo el uso de: `super().__init__(co, ru, ve, ci)` o `Coche.__init__(self, co, ru, ve, ci)` es casi lo mismo.

`super` lo que hace es llamar directamente a la clase de la que hereda, es decir, `Coche`, por lo tanto te da igual poner `Coche` que `super`. Aunque hay dos diferencias.

### 1. MRO

Usando `Super` se implementa el [método de resolución de búsqueda (Method Resolution Search, MRO)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) que crea un grafo de dependencia entre las clases, esto además de ser el método de resolución de herencias en Python por defecto, resuelve el [problema del diamante](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_del_diamante). Así se ayuda a la resolución de errores durante la herencia, mejor debugging, etc.

Si quieres ver más sobre el algoritmo `MRO` puedes verlo en la [documentación oficial de Python](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/)

### 2. Convención

La forma convencional (aunque muchas veces no se vea en la mayoría de los códigos) es usar `super`.Esto hace más sencilla la interpretación de tu código. Si aparece `super` **el programador** que ve el código ya **sabe que está heredando de las clases padres** y no tiene que liarse buscando qué es `Coche`.